# Bootstrap 4 Carousel sliders not working

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-4

I'm having some serious issues with getting by carousel to go onto the next slide. I may be missing something very basic but regardless of what I do, it doesn't seem to be working! I've tried using the Javascript as well but to no avail.

```
            <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel-slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                    <h1 class="header-h1">WE'RE READY, ARE YOU? </h1>
                    <H2 class="header-h2">COME AND JOIN US FOR A SHOOT</H2>
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">FIND OUT MORE</a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
                    <h1 class="header-h1">COME AND </h1>
                    <H2 class="header-h2">HAVE</H2>
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-default">A GO</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's just `class="carousel slide"`, not class="carousel-slide"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this still hasnt working :(

Comment: Carousel class is not as per bootstrap. So follow bootstrap guide

Comment: The code (other than `class="carousel-slide"`) will work. Make sure you've properly include Bootstrap and dependencies (jquery, popper.js, bootstrap.js, etc..). Did you check the many other carousel questions? Are there errors in the browser console?

Comment: So the carousel is working automatically now, but the manual option to go to next and previous still isn't working (sorry, bootstrap novice here! :) )

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the following working carousel slider template as a starting point (including all of the CDN files in the exact same order you see them in the template) and then start replacing parts of that template with your own content one by one.

Only do it one piece at a time and as soon as something you add breaks the whole thing, you'll immediately know the culprit.

Here's the working template (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="First slide">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
                <p>The whole caption will only show up if the screen is at least medium size.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having a melt down trying to get this to work. +1

Comment: I have updated from BS 3.x to BS 4.x. In my case, the items were not handled correct (showed vertically instead of change inplace), In my case, I had to change the class item to carousel-item.

Comment: Thanks, only when i click next the image gets bigger. Am gonna fix that now

Comment: thanks, @FredyWenger I face same issue BS3 to BS4 carousel, class "item" to "carousel-item"

Comment: From bs 4.5+ it seams that slide does not work anymore. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/ and see that images changes without sliding