# Bootstrap 5 - Carousel won't slide to next image - upgrade from bootstrap 4 to bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, bootstrap-5

So I have the bootstrap 5 library downloaded - both the `compiled css and js` and the `source files`. I have tried both of them - the css loads well from what I can tell - yet, I can't get [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48826241/3155240) to work from a related post on boostrap 4, which should work for bootstrap 5... I am trying to avoid using CDNs to provide the libraries, hence why I downloaded them. When I use the CDNs provided in the example it works like a charm.

Can someone point me to what the heck I am missing to make the carousel work? What file(s) do I need to reference to make it slide?

(Here is some code so I don't get yelled at)

I am using dJango and when I check the console I have no resource errors.

Once again, when I use the BS 4 CDN everything works...

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Welcome!
    </title>
<!--
uncomment this and it works

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

the problem is the below
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

    <!--example:-->
    <!--href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}"-->

    <!--theme-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="{% static 'favicon/CES.png' %}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/main.css' %}">

    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="{% static 'Java/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Java/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Java/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Java/jQuery/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->


    <!--bootstrap related-->
    <!--
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--
this is the problem...
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
</head>
<body>

    <!--Image Carosel-->
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
                        <p>The whole caption will only show up if the screen is at least medium size.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have to go to bed and do things in the morning... I will be up in like 12 hours - so no rush.

Comment: what?  looks like you're loading 4 different variants of jquery and 4 different variants of BS5 ... and I don't think any of them are actually loaded.

Comment: @Vino They are all loaded - I changed the path in the code example (so if you're familiar with django they look wonky - I have my reasons for that) and despite that change the console didn't throw any errors. I was desperately trying to solve the problem so I included all of the js and css files and narrowed it down to 2 imports. In the end Paolo Cava's answer did the trick for me - I was unaware that that was a change made to BS 5 after reading the "new features" list. Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To migrate from version 4 to 5 you have to change the data values, for example data-bs-target instead of data-target.

In your case, just make simple changes

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>

        <!--Image Carosel-->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/animals" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>My Caption Title (1st Image)</h5>
                            <p>The whole caption will only show up if the screen is at least medium size.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/arch" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/1080/500/nature" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Now the only problem is that when the slide changes it expands to be the width of the page... but let me try to tackle that one and if I get hung up I will open another thread.