# bootstrap carrousel in portfolio doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a portfolio for a learning project. below is my code

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equive="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Portfolio</title>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-custom">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logoimg" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"
                        style="width: 30%;"></a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <!-- <img src="images/Home_free_icon.svg" alt="Home" style="width: 5%;"> -->
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Compétences</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tarifs</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">À Propos</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/rrr.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/Home_free_icon.svg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}

header::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header nav.navbar {
    z-index: 999;
}

header nav.navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

header nav.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item {}

/* Modify the background color */
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: white;
}

.logoimg {
    transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}

.logoimg:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}



.nav-item::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-item:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
}

.nav-link {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: red;
}

.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
    color: red;
}

.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
    background: red;
}

.navtext:hover {
    color: red;
}

.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat scroll center scroll;
}
```

I tried to introduce a carousel to my portfolio, I took a carousel from the official bootstrap site but it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out the error but I can't see where it is. I watched videos I checked tutorials but with everyone it works from what I saw. I followed the steps in the tutorial but it still doesn't work, can someone tell me how to solve this bootstrap problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste the code in the below answer to check if that works,
[Bootstrap 4 Carousel sliders not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48824568/bootstrap-4-carousel-sliders-not-working)

If the above code also did not work for you, the error is definitely of the version of bootstrap used, so upgrade or downgrade to check

Also sometimes, some adblockers restrict the sliding in localhost, try opening the portfolio in the incognito tab

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have see this topic before i have try to add the same link like in this topic but this is doesn't work for me. But thanks for your help i have change link of version bootstrap and this work now. thanks you very much